# Hibernate Envers rev column data type is Integer

Tags: hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envers in my application to store audit trail data, all audit related information are storing in *_AUD table correctly. However, the data type of rev column in all _AUD table is Integer data type. I am expecting a big int data type because the maximum range of integer data type is 2147483647. Is there a way to change the data type to big int?

Comment: Isn't this column used for revision a single tuple? means: a tuple can have  2147483647 revisions, which should be enough...

Comment: No. Envers obtain the revision number for all AUD table from 1 sequence number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the Envers implementation uses an `Integer` data type for the `REV` column.

In order to leverage a `Long` data type, you'll need to supply a custom revision entity with the appropriate annotations.  Below is an example that will replace the existing default implementation while using a `BIGINT` compatible `REV` column.

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity
public class CustomRevisionEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @RevisionNumber
  private Long rev;
  @RevisionTimestamp
  private Long timestamp;
  /* provide getter/setters */
}
```

*NOTE: All audit tables will make their `REV` column's data type match that of the data type you use in the revision entity class.*

There is an open JIRA [HHH-6615](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6615) to migrate the default implementations to use `Long` instead of `Integer` based revisions; however, it does require that we consider upgrade paths as a implementation detail of that issue to account for existing users.

Until then, using a custom revision entity for new implementations is a workaround.